# Is there example of 'not open and. not closed set' in usual topology on real line?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{\mathbb{R})$ the real number with the standard topology (that is the topology of order or equivalently the induced topology by the metric,) 
 Is there a set which is not open and not closed? .

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: What about the interval $(0,1],$ for example?

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Thank you. Then product topology about  (usual topology on real line)×(discrete topology in real line), $(0,1]×{y}$ ({y} is any point subset)  can be closed set on product topology?

Comment: Since your are new. When someone give you an answer and that you think that the answer is good and correct you can can approve the question to give some credit to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all n $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n $ is not open and not closed .(with the usual topology) 
The closure of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n $ and this follow from the fact that all real number can be approach by rational number.
The interior is the empty set .

Answer (score 0):

An example of a subset of $\mathbb R$ that is not open and not closed in the usual topology

is a half-open interval $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$ with $a<b$.